# Python - Test requests with retry and timeout

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, django-testing

I have the following piece of Python code and I would like to write tests for this function:

```py
def http_request(method, url)
    session = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.5, status_forcelist=list(range(500, 600)))
    for prefix in ('http://', 'https://'):
        session.mount(prefix,   HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    response = session.request(method, url, timeout=(31,123))
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response
```

Now I would like to write a unit test for this function, but I'm a bit lost.

How can I test that :

1. There are indeed 3 retries (so 4 calls in total) if the status is between 500-600?
2. The timeouts are respected.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to test? if `requests` library is working as expected?

Comment: Basically, yes.. But now I'm wondering if this is really useful to test the `http_request` method because it contains only `requests` features